# Error while Passing values from JavaScript to code behind function

Tags: javascript, asp.net, webforms

I am trying to change the text value of `button1` on click of another `button2` then fetching the text value of `button1` in code behind on click event of `button1` triggered through JavaScript.

Button Definition

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" OnClick="Button1_Click" />
<asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" CssClass="Button2" Text="Button2_Old" />
```

JavaScript Value set & button click

```
<script>
    $(document).on("click", ".Button2", function () {
        var clientid = document.getElementById("<%=Button1.ClientID %>");
        clientid.value = "XYZ";
        alert(document.getElementById("<%=Button1.ClientID %>").value);
        document.getElementById("<%=Button1.ClientID %>").click();
    });
</script>
```

Code Behind

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string x = Button1.Text;
}
```

I am not able to get the updated value at code behind. No error, No hit on breakpoint. Please guide me.

Comment: Make sure you are not resetting the values in `Page_Load` method.

Comment: There are no lines or code in page load method.Moreover upon button1 click, it should hit break point. But no :(

Comment: Okay, then it means you are not actually posting back correctly. Can you see console for javascript errors?

Comment: When you click `Button2`, it does a post back (because it's marked `runat="server"`) so it never runs your script.

Comment: No, It's not like that. i am getting alert for alert(document.getElementById("<%=Button1.ClientID %>").value); as "XYZ".

Comment: try using this command to click button 1 `__doPostBack('<%= Button1.ClientID  %>', '');` and also `return false;` in the javascript at the end of `button2` click.

Comment: @JamshaidKamran Nope..!! No error in console.

Comment: then just return false at the end of javacript click event and see what happens.

Comment: After adding return false; Break point got a hit but Button1 text value is blank not as it should be "XYZ".

Comment: Button2 causes a postback which resets the page to *what is in the markup*, not the changes you made on the front end. Js does not permanently change the markup.